# Removing WPML Items From the WordPress Admin Bar

Tags: functions, admin

I'm using WPML on a website, and since I'm traducting everyting mylsef, I want to hide the "WPML Translation managment" section.
[image]

I tried with :
function my_remove_menu_pages() {
remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=tm/menu/main.php' );  //
};  add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_menu_pages', 999 );

in my function.php but it's not working.

If someone have a solution, please could you help me ?

Thank you !

Lea

Answer (score 0):

There might be some specific related to your site. Did you try contacting WPML support? In the past they have offered a few possible solutions:

- https://wpml.org/forums/topic/hide-wpml-submenu-from-admin-sidebar/
- https://wpml.org/forums/topic/cannot-hide-wpml-from-admin-sidebar-anymore/

Or you can use some plugin that can be used to hide menu items, e.g. https://www.greengeeks.com/tutorials/hide-admin-menu-items-for-specific-users-in-wordpress/